How to speed up fitting linear mixed model on subsets of data?
I am trying to fit linear mixed models for all possible combinations of factors that I have on my dataset. Since it is taking too long to finish running, I really need to optimize my code.
To illustrate what I am doing, let's take as an example the sleepstudy data from the lme4 package:
# Load required packages
library(lmerTest)
library(data.table)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)

# Prepare example data
sleepstudy <- data.table(sleepstudy)
sleepstudy[, Subject := as.character(Subject)]

sleepstudy contains 18 subjects with repeated measurements of reaction time taken on different days. For the sake of simplicity, I will use only the first 9 subjects:
# Get unique subjects - use only the 9 first subjects to prevent code from taking forever to run
unique_subjects <- unique(sleepstudy$Subject)
unique_subjects <- unique_subjects[1:9]

Next, I create a vector with all possible combinations of the 9 subjects selected in the previous step. As a result, there are 502 unique combinations of subjects that I will have to fit a mixed linear model on:
# Generate all possible combinations of subjects
combinations <- lapply(2:length(unique_subjects), function(n) combn(unique_subjects, n, simplify = TRUE))
combinations <- do.call(c, lapply(combinations, asplit, 2))

Last, for each one of the 502 combinations of subjects I do the following:
- subset the current combination from the original table;
- fit a linear model;
- estimate group means and prepare a resulting table with statistical significance between subjects denoted by letters like a, b, c, and combinations like ab, bc
# Fit models for each combination
res <- lapply(1:length(combinations), function(i) {
  
  # subset table for specific subject combination
  subset_dt <- sleepstudy[Subject %in% combinations[[i]]]
  
  # fit model
  lmer_model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Subject + (1|Days), data = subset_dt)
  
  # create table including letter display of all pair-wise comparisons 
  lw.comp <- data.table(cld(emmeans(lmer_model, pairwise ~ Subject),
                            level=0.95, Letters=LETTERS))
  
  # create new column with list of subjects taken into account in the model
  setcolorder(lw.comp[, list_subjects := paste(combinations[[i]], collapse=",")], c('list_subjects'))
  
  return(lw.comp)
})

# combine results
(comb.dt <- rbindlist(res))


However, it takes too long to run. Perhaps not so much on this toy example, but my real dataset has over 50k combinations in total. Therefore, I need to find some way to optimize this code.
Is there any native data-table solution that can run this "internaly", without using lapply to subset each combination?
I can not use any mclapply for his specific code, since I am already using it to parallellize an outer loop over all the data files that I have to extract the subjects combinations from.

OP already said they're parallelizing at the outer level.  Using an optimized BLAS may help. If you just want to replace a fixed-effect predictor but keep everything else the same there may be some hackery you can do.

Maybe have a look at the glmulti package, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/index.html demo here https://youtu.be/Im293ClFen4?feature=shared. It has multiple exploration technique.

Are you certain that there's no way to "weed out" the majority of combinations, based on some other parameter, prior to running the linfits?   would it be acceptable to find a filtering parameter that is, say,  95% accurate in doing such a sub-selection?

@BenBolker unfortunately BLAS does not seem to help much. "Optimized BLAS does not seem to help much." Quoted from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmerperf.html

@CarlWitthoft Yes I am. Each combination is a commercial one, and I really need to take all of them into account.

What platform are you using? If a laptop, you're probably using all cores already so more parallelization can't help. But on a cluster you can easily add another parallelization layer with pbdMPI. As for the lack of help from faster BLAS, it's likely because those parts are implemented in C++ without the BLAS. Likely reason is that pivoting in QR done by BLAS breaks interpretation in lme4.

I wouldn't conclude that optimized BLAS won't help your particular situation. I would expect the performance difference to vary a lot by situation. For example, this post does report a benefit of optimized BLAS.

tl;dr I have a couple of tricks that will make lme4 a little bit faster, but:

they are fairly specific to the structure of your example, and might not apply to your real use case if it is somewhat different ...
they don't help very much (certainly not by an order of magnitude)
benchmarking and profiling suggest that most of the time is actually being taken by the emmeans call, not by lmer.
for this example at least, running the function once for the largest subset (all 9 subjects) takes about 150 milliseconds on my laptop. By my calculations that means that 50K combinations would take 5e4*150*0.001/60=125 minutes. Is that really too long for a substantive data analysis? (Again, it's possible that individual fits for your real example are bigger/slower than this ...)

fitting function
Here is an enhanced version of your core fitting function.  It allows the following additional options:

specify starting values for the parameters to speed up optimization (in a linear mixed model, the only explicit parameters are the random-effects (co)variance parameters, and in this example there is only one, the standard deviation of the among-Subject variation in the intercept)
use the refit() option to refit the model with a different vector of response variables. This only works in this case because of a very specific structure, which is that the vector of fixed-effect covariates is the same for every subject (i.e., the design is balanced), and that subjects are exchangeable. Also note that in this case we have to pass a base model with the same data dimensions as the subset we're going to refit, so we would have to do a separate loop (or nest loops) for each set of combinations with a particular number of subjects ...
returning only the coefficients, bailing out before the emmeans calculations

ff1 <- function(i, start = NULL, base_model = NULL, refit = FALSE, coefs_only = FALSE) {
    ## subset table for specific subject combination
    subset_dt <- sleepstudy[Subject %in% combinations[[i]]]
    ## fit model
    if (!refit) {
        lmer_model <- update(base_model, data = subset_dt, start = start)
    } else {
        lmer_model <- refit(base_model, newresp = subset_dt$Reaction)
    }
    if (coefs_only) return(fixef(lmer_model))
    ## create table including letter display of all pair-wise comparisons 
    lw.comp <- data.table(cld(emmeans(lmer_model, pairwise ~ Subject),
                              level=0.95, Letters=LETTERS))
    ## create new column with list of subjects taken into account in the model
    setcolorder(lw.comp[, list_subjects := paste(combinations[[i]], collapse=",")], c('list_subjects'))
    return(lw.comp)
}

evaluation
Now let's see how this performs, first with the smallest combinations (only two subjects):
fit base model
lmer1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Subject + (1|Days),
                  data = subset(sleepstudy, Subject %in% combinations[[1]]))
##
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(baseline = ff1(1, base_model = lmer1),
               good_start = ff1(1, base_model = lmer1, start = getME(lmer_base,"theta")),
               refit = ff1(1, base_model = lmer1, refit = TRUE),
               coefs_only = ff1(1, base_model = lmer1, refit = TRUE, coefs_only = TRUE)
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
   baseline 71.355103 73.124095 75.752385 74.771380 77.15065 93.44492   100 a  
 good_start 69.842636 72.537420 75.942336 74.816134 77.87323 91.91398   100 a  
      refit 55.134464 56.712845 58.763176 58.028897 60.14157 75.98236   100  b 
 coefs_only  6.284897  6.937626  7.233845  7.142845  7.38023 11.42668   100   c

Conclusions so far:

setting the starting value doesn't help very much (in this case);
using refit speeds things up by approximately 25% (from a mean of 75 to 58 ms)
returning only the coefficients (skipping emmeans calculations) speeds things up tenfold.

Maybe this is an artifact of using the smallest example, with only two subjects: what if we use the largest combination (all 9 subjects)?
## refit base model to last combination (all 9 subjects)
lmer2 <- update(lmer_base,
                     data = subset(sleepstudy, Subject %in% combinations[[502]]))
microbenchmark(baseline = ff1(502, base_model = lmer2),
               good_start = ff1(502, base_model = lmer2, start = getME(lmer2,"theta")),
               refit = ff1(502, base_model = lmer2, refit = TRUE),
               coefs_only = ff1(502, base_model = lmer2, refit = TRUE, coefs_only = TRUE)
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max  neval cld
   baseline 146.370169 150.685938 157.295938 154.291821 157.025863 322.54636    100 a  
 good_start 145.514585 151.198449 153.941184 154.273386 156.794318 168.84127    100 a  
      refit 127.749710 132.707177 136.826251 137.163430 140.308683 152.99645    100  b 
 coefs_only   6.386507   7.239992   7.515005   7.456434   7.604491  12.60484    100   c

Takes twice as long for the baseline, but all of this is from the emmeans calculation — if we skip it (with coefs_only) we are back the the 7.5 ms timing!
profiling
I originally realized that emmeans might be the bottleneck by profiling the code. (I'm using a profiling summarizer written by Noam Ross here, source()d from a github repository ... (Please check the code here for yourself before blindly sourcing it ...)
Rprof("lmerprof.out")
x <- replicate(100, ff1(1, refit_model = lmer_base))
Rprof(NULL)

source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noamross/noamtools/master/R/proftable.R")
proftable("lmerprof.out", 20)

 PctTime   Call                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 11.604    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > try > tryCatch > tryCatchList > tryCatchOne > doTryCatch > recover_data > .get.outside.method > utils::getAnywhere > find > %in% > ls            
  8.874    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > emm_basis > .get.outside.method > utils::getAnywhere > find > %in% > ls                                                                          
  8.874    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > emm_basis > utils::getAnywhere > find > %in% > ls                                                                                                
  5.461    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > try > tryCatch > tryCatchList > tryCatchOne > doTryCatch > recover_data > utils::getAnywhere > find > %in% > ls                                  
  4.096    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > try > tryCatch > tryCatchList > tryCatchOne > doTryCatch > recover_data > recover_data.merMod > utils::getAnywhere > find > %in% > ls            
  0.683    data.table > cld > emmeans > apply > fac.reduce                                                                                                                                                       
  0.683    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous>                                                                                                                                                    
  0.683    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > emm_basis > emm_basis.merMod > pbkrtest::vcovAdj.lmerMod > vcovAdj_internal > * > new > initialize > callNextMethod > .nextMethod > validObject >
  0.683    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > emm_basis > emm_basis.merMod > pbkrtest::vcovAdj.lmerMod > vcovAdj_internal > + > new > initialize > callNextMethod > .nextMethod > validObject >
  0.683    data.table > cld > emmeans > do.call > <Anonymous> > try > tryCatch > tryCatchList > tryCatchOne > doTryCatch > recover_data > recover_data.merMod > .has.fcns > setdiff > as.vector > .all.vars > gsu
  0.683    refit > refit.merMod > <Anonymous> > do.call > methods::new > initialize                                                                                                                              
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > .mcletters > multcompView::multcompLetters > vec2mat2 > t > as.matrix > as.matrix.data.frame                                          
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > .mcletters > multcompView::multcompLetters > vec2mat2 > t > as.matrix > as.matrix.data.frame > vapply                                 
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > .mcletters > unlist > substr                                                                                                          
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > .mcletters > unlist > match.fun                                                                                                       
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > <Anonymous> > getClass > getClassDef > .getClassesFromCache                                                                           
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > contrast > contrast.emmGrid > t > t.data.frame > as.matrix > as.matrix.data.frame > as.list                                           
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > do.call > <Anonymous> > test.emmGrid > summary > summary.emmGrid > .est.se.df > t > apply > pbkrtest::Lb_ddf > [ > .subscript.2ary > .
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > do.call > <Anonymous> > test.emmGrid > summary > summary.emmGrid > .est.se.df > t > apply > pbkrtest::Lb_ddf > * > .Ops.checkDimNames 
  0.341    data.table > cld > cld.emm_list > multcomp::cld > cld.emmGrid > do.call > <Anonymous> > test.emmGrid > summary > summary.emmGrid > .est.se.df > t > apply > pbkrtest::Lb_ddf > * > new > initialize > 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      Parent Call: replicate > sapply > lapply > FUN > ff1 > ...                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      Total Time: 5.86 seconds                                                                                                                                                                               
      Percent of run time represented: 46.1 %>                                                                                                                                                               

